# A problem with a break function in a while loop that doesn't work

Tags: c, list, matrix, while-loop, break

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define SPN 4
#define BTT 50 
#define MARKER 'X'



void create_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);
void create_roulette(int list[BTT]);
void print_card(int matriz[SPN][SPN], int list[BTT], int i);
bool win_coll(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);
bool win_arow(int matriz[SPN][SPN]);


// 1. function
void create_card_game(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    for(int i=0; i<SPN; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
        {
            matriz[i][j]=rand()%25;
        }
    }
}


// 2. function
void create_roulette(int list[BTT])
{
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        list[i]=rand()%20;
    }
}


// 3. function
void print_card(int matriz[SPN][SPN], int list[BTT], int i)
{
    for(int i=0; i<BTT; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
        {
            for(int n=0; n<SPN; n++)
            {
                if(matriz[j][n] == 88 || matriz[j][n] == list[i])
                {
                    matriz[j][n]=MARKER;
                    printf("|");
                    printf("%2c", matriz[j][n]);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("|");
                    printf("%2d", matriz[j][n]);
                }
            }
            printf("|\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf(" e o numero escolhido e: %2d", list[i]);
        printf("\n");
        while(win_arow(matriz) || win_coll(matriz))
        {
            printf("vitoria");
            break;
        }
        getchar();
    }
}


// 4. function
bool win_coll(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    int i=0;
    for(int j=0; j<SPN; j++)
    {
        if(matriz[i][j]==88 && matriz[i+1][j]==88 && matriz[i+2][j]==88 && matriz[i+3][j]==88) 
        {    
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


// 5. function
bool win_arow(int matriz[SPN][SPN])
{
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0; i<SPN; i++)
    {
        if(matriz[i][j]==88 && matriz[i][j+1]==88 && matriz[i][j+2]==88 && matriz[i][j+3]==88)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}



int main()
{
    int card_game_player[SPN][SPN];
    int roulette[BTT];
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
// Create Player 1 and Player 2 Matriz
    create_card_game(card_game_player);   

// Create Roulette List 
    create_roulette(roulette);

// Print Player 1 and Player 2 Card Game     
    for(int n=0; n<BTT; n++)
    {
        print_card(card_game_player, roulette, n);
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code for the purpose of testing the `win_coll` and `win_arow`. I will summarize the functions presented:

1. It aims to create a matrix and fill it with random numbers.
2. Do the same as 1. but for a list.
3. First the function will go through the list and matrix looking for equality between them and when affirmative the number of the matrix in question will be replaced by int 88, it also has the objective of printing both and when the matrix presents int 88 this will be replaced by the char 'X'. Finally, when any of the functions `win_coll` or `win_arow` become true, `"victoria"` will be printed and the program will stop completely.
4. Its objective is to verify if any column is completely filled by int 88.
5. Same as 4. but now for lines.

The problem lies in the fact that when the function `win_coll` or `win_arow` the program prints victory but does not stop even the break function is in a while loop. How can i change it?

Comment: The `break` only breaks out of the `while` loop. The surrounding `for` loop is not affected by it

Comment: replace `break` with `return` if you're done with that function when you `printf("vitoria");`. That may violate some arbitrarily defined coding standards somewhere, but it never makes sense to me to hang around when we're done or add more lines of code to "naturally" break from all the loops.

Comment: `while(win_arow(matriz) || win_coll(matriz))` --> `if(win_arow(matriz) || win_coll(matriz))`??? This will break the inner `for` loop at least